# Oracle trigger for inserting distinct values

Tags: oracle, triggers

there are two oracle tables `tab1` and `tab2`. `tab1` has multiple rows with same name;  after insert or update with same name on `tab1` need to get distinct name from  `tab1` and insert /update into `tab2` columns (name , curr_date). Please guide

for example
Tab1 :

```
Name  group City 
----  ----- ----
Alex   B1     NY
Alex   C1     EU
Alex   BC     AP
Alex   A      AP
```

Tab2:

```
Name  Curr_date
----  ---------
Alex  2021-11-19
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need/ want a trigger rather than having `tab2` be a view or a materialized view?  What is `curr_date` supposed to represent?  The last time an "Alex" row was inserted?  The last time an "Alex" row was modified?  The literal current date?  Something else?

Comment: use a view. trigger here does not make any sense at all